# Incorrect Results using SUM()

Tags: sql

I am not sure where I have gone wrong. I am trying to count the number of hours and endpoints for a company, per agreement. My SUM() results, however, are wildly off-course.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT v_rpt_Company.Company_Name, v_rpt_Service.agreement_name, 
   COUNT(DISTINCT v_rpt_Service.TicketNbr) AS tickets, 
   SUM(ISNULL(v_rpt_Service.Hours_Agreement, 0)) AS hours, 
   SUM(ISNULL(AGR_Detail.AGD_Qty, 0)) AS endpoints
FROM AGR_Header 
    INNER JOIN v_rpt_Service 
        ON AGR_Header.AGR_Header_RecID = v_rpt_Service.AGR_Header_RecID 
    INNER JOIN v_rpt_Company 
        ON v_rpt_Service.company_recid = v_rpt_Company.Company_RecID AND 
            AGR_Header.Company_RecID = v_rpt_Company.Company_RecID 
    INNER JOIN AGR_Detail 
        ON AGR_Header.AGR_Header_RecID = AGR_Detail.AGR_Header_RecID
WHERE        
    (v_rpt_Service.date_entered >= DATEADD(day, - 30, GETDATE())) 
    AND 
    (v_rpt_Company.Company_RecID = 
        CASE 
            WHEN @Company <> - 1 THEN @Company 
            ELSE v_rpt_Company.Company_RecID 
        END) 
    AND 
    (v_rpt_Service.AGR_Header_RecID = 
        CASE 
            WHEN @Agreement <> - 1 THEN @Agreement 
            ELSE v_rpt_Service.AGR_Header_RecID 
        END)
GROUP BY v_rpt_Company.Company_Name, v_rpt_Service.agreement_name
ORDER BY v_rpt_Company.Company_Name, v_rpt_Service.agreement_name
```

Comment: Can you make a SQL Fiddle or give us some example datasets and resultsets that you are working with? http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: And add a short description of your table schema?

Comment: I can't really give you too much information on the table (confidential client information) but here is the data dictionary for the database I am working with : https://www.connectwise.com/University/Content/documents/DataDictionary.pdf

Comment: Is the Count(Distinct...) field giving you what you expected?

Comment: The fact that DISTINCT is used when getting a COUNT of v_rpt_Service.TicketNbr implies that the records retrieved from that table are not distinct, which is why the SUM of hours is wrong. Duplicate ticket numbers = duplicate hours.

Comment: @David Removing "DISTINCT" Produces the same results. The ticket numbers are unique.

Davin If I add "DISTINCT" to the SUM()s, It is incorrect because some of the values I am summing are the same.

Comment: Gut-feeling NULLs + IN() clauses. Hint to the OP: the query would be more readable if you'd use correlation names instead of the long table names.

Comment: @DavidFaber You ended up being right. Because some other data was different, it ended up pulling duplicate ticket numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT      v_rpt_Company.Company_Name, v_rpt_Service.agreement_name, COUNT(DISTINCT v_rpt_Service.TicketNbr) AS tickets, 
                         SUM(ISNULL(v_rpt_Service.Hours_Actual, 0)) AS hours,( SUM(ISNULL(AGR_Detail.AGD_Qty, 0))/COUNT(DISTINCT v_rpt_Service.TicketNbr)) AS endpoints
```

That ended up being the correct result. Thank you DavidFaber.

Answer (score 0):

To debug cases like this, you should set up a test database, probably on your development computer where you can drop all tables at any time, rebuild the schema and load test data with specific test cases.

Use tools like [dbunit](http://www.dbunit.org/) for this. That way, you can be sure that the SQL works as expected, even when the requirements change.

If your test cases work but the result in the production DB fails, copy part of the production DB into your development DB and create a new test case.

Answer (score 0):

The second part of your WHERE clause isn't going to work as planned:

```
(v_rpt_Company.Company_RecID = 
    CASE 
        WHEN @Company <> - 1 THEN @Company 
        ELSE v_rpt_Company.Company_RecID 
    END)
```

the ELSE part will match the current record if @Company=-1, essentially making the result always true.

Comment: That is exactly what I want. If the parameter contains a company id, show that company. Otherwise, show All companies.